# How to code the displaying the graphical object - arrow representing the substring of string in OS X program by using Xcode and swift 2

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I have two strings. One string is substring of other. I know index range of substring. I would like to show in window of my program the graphical object - arrow representing the substring in a position beneath the string. Length and position of the substring should be according to the index range of substring in the string. What should I do in xcode using swift 2. I need all possible advices both general and more detailed. I have never tried before to present string as graphical object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Text Kit "stack" and supply your own NSLayoutManager subclass. This is the class that has charge of drawing the string, so you can draw the arrow as part of that. The NSLayoutManager knows where all the "letters" (glyphs) of the original string are being drawn, so you'll easily be able to put the arrow in the right place.

(For example, that is how Xcode draws the "cartouche" elements representing placeholders when you enter a method using code completion. It replaces the drawing of the placeholder letters, such as `"<#code#>"`,  with the drawing of the cartouche.)

In this screen shot, the rectangle around the word is drawn through an NSLayoutManager subclass:

[image]

The technique for drawing an arrow under part of a word would be similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a text view and want it to render the text as normal, you don't need to use a custom `NSLayoutManager` subclass. You can simply query the text view's normal `layoutManager` for the location(s) of a range of characters.

You can call `-rectArrayForCharacterRange:withinSelectedCharacterRange:inTextContainer:rectCount:` on the text view's `layoutManager`. Note that this may give multiple rects for two reasons: 1) the characters in the range may have been split across multiple lines, and 2) the characters may include bidirectional text and be non-contiguous.

The rectangles are relative to the text container. You can query the text view's `textContainer` property to get it to pass to the above method. Also, you need to adjust the rectangles by the `textContainerOrigin` to convert from text container coordinates to text view coordinates.

Comment: This is cool but I'm not grasping how it adds his extra drawing (the arrow under the substring) to the drawing of the text that the layout manager performs. I use a custom NSLayoutManager because I need to override the draw-glyph commands. I don't see how you can do that without an NSLayoutManager subclass. My approach works fine in a text view but AFAICT that text view needs to be given an NSLayoutManager subclass. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @matt: It doesn't **do** the drawing, it gives his `drawRect()` implementation the information it needs to do the drawing. He would use the position of the text range as given by the layout manager method I mention to determine where to put his arrow.

Comment: But where would he draw it? The text view is scrollable. He has nothing to draw into. The layout manager, on the other hand, has a text container linked to the text view content itself. It lives, as it were, in a graphic context world. And he's not going to override `drawRect` for a text view!

Comment: @matt: Well, he could use a subclass of `NSTextView` and override its `drawRect()`. That would call through to super and then draw the arrow.

Comment: I really don't think you're invited to override a text view's `drawRect`. But hey, OS X is not my thing, maybe things are different there! :) What I can tell you is that stuff like colored underlines and placeholder cartouches that you see in a code editor like Xcode are done with the NSLayoutManager.